# Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging - rollInterval

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, logging-application-block

Can the [Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569.aspx) be configured to roll the log file every day at a specified time (e.g. at 3:00 PM)?

The relevant options of [`rollInterval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.tracelisteners.rollinterval.aspx) are `day` and `midnight`. I'm not sure what the difference is, but `midnight` certainly isn't the right choice, and I don't see how to configure at what hour to perform a roll when using `day` (is it actually identical to `midnight`?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the RollInterval is set to Midnight the log file will roll after midnight (i.e. the next day).  If the RollInterval is set to Day then the log file will roll after a full day has passed since the log file was created (i.e. 24 hours from the start).

I don't believe that the LoggingApplication Block has a setting to roll the log file at a specific time.  If you wanted that functionality, you would have to create a custom Trace Listener (which can be based on the existing Rolling Flat File Trace Listener).

The Caching Application Block provides an [`ExtendedFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.caching.expirations.extendedformat%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) for cache item expirations that could be used as the basis of a more flexible rolling file "expiration" scheme.